# remove password from libreoffice calc or excel file in terminal

Tags: password, libreoffice

I like passwords and security but once a file is safely on my encrypted drive it can become an annoyance and overkill having it there.

The following command nicely and cleanly removes the password from a pdf permanently :

```
qpdf --password=somethingsecret --decrypt myfile_locked.pdf myfile_unlocked.pdf
```

Is there a similar command which will do this for an .xlsx or .ods file?